# Solve the roots of a cubic polynomial?

Tags: polynomials

I have had trouble with this question - mainly due to the fact that I do not fully understand what a 'geometric progression' is:

"Solve the equation $x^3 - 14x^2 + 56x - 64 = 0$" if the roots are in geometric progression.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression) the roots are of the form $a, ar, ar^2$.

Here it is not too difficult to see that $2, 4, 8$ are ok, just look at the constant term, which is $- (a \cdot ar \cdot ar^2) = - (a r)^3$, and check that $2, 4, 8$ fit with the other coefficients
$$
14 = 2 + 4 + 8,
\qquad
56 = 2 \cdot 4 + 2 \cdot 8 + 4 \cdot 8.
$$

Comment: Thanks, but are there different types of geometric progessions?

Comment: @missiledragon, not that I am aware of, it means a sequence of the form $a_{n} = a r^{n}$ for some $a, r$, see the Wikipedia link.

Comment: Thanks, if you don't mind, could you briefly explain what an arithmetic progression is? I had a similar question with it.

Comment: @missiledragon, the Wikipedia is your friend http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression it means a sequence of the form $a_{n} = a + n r$, for fixed $a, r$, and $n \ge 0$.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your help

Comment: @missiledragon, you're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Let the roots be $a,a\cdot r,a\cdot r^2$

Using [Vieta's formula](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Vieta%27s_Formulas)  $a+a\cdot r+a\cdot r^2=14\implies a(1+r+r^2)=14$

and $a(a\cdot r)+a\cdot r(a\cdot r^2)+a(a\cdot r^2)=56\implies a^2\cdot r(1+r+r^2)=56$

On division, $ar=4$ as $a\cdot r\ne0$

$$\implies a=\frac 4r\implies \frac{4(1+r+r^2)}r=14\implies 2r^2-5r+2=0\implies r=2\text{  or }\frac12$$

---

Alternatively, 
 using Vieta's formula $a\cdot(a\cdot r) \cdot (a\cdot r^2)=64\implies (ar)^3=64$

So, $a\cdot r$ can be one of $4,4w,4w^2$ where $w$ is the cube root of $1$

Using [Polynomial Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem), observe that $4$ is a root of the given equation

$\implies a\cdot r=4\iff a=\frac4r$

Again, using Vieta's formula $a+a\cdot r+a\cdot r^2=14\implies 2r^2-5r+2=0$

Comment: Why is $a$ multiplied by $r$ ?

Comment: @missiledragon, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricSeries.html

Comment: @missiledragon, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression

Comment: Wait, isn't it $ar(1+r+r^2)=56$ supposed to have $ar^2$ instead?

Comment: Yep, I used his formula.

Comment: No worries. Are you going to fix the rest of the answer?

Comment: How did you get: $4(1+r+r^2)/r$?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8776/discussion-between-lab-bhattacharjee-and-missiledragon)